# Keyboard shortcut for opening Google Chrome's Wrench menu

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any key combination for opening the menu (I mean the button having as icon a tool placed on the right hand side of the address bar)?  I couldn't find anything on Google so far

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under Windows or Linux, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> - Either of these combinations will [open](https://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=157179) Chrome's Wrench menu.

Comment: How would you do it on a Mac?